# Why doesn't the L'Hopital's Rule work in this case?

Tags: calculus, limits

The following limit evaluates to 1 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x + \sin x}{x} = 1 + \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

But when I use L'Hopital's rule, it doesn't:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+\sin x}{x} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\cos x}{1}  = 1+\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos x$$

Why doesn't L'Hopital's rule work here? What conditions does it not satisfy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'Hopital's Rule says that **if** the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ exists, **then** $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. In your case, the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does **not** exist. So, there is no contradiction here.